# Time to enumerate all values in n bits

Tags: cpu, bit, enumerate

I am looking for the theoretical time it would take to go through all the possible values that can be encoded in n bits, with n being big (say, 80).
I understand this would require a few instructions i.e. a test, an addition and a jump. But I can't figure out how the CPU will manage these operations on such a number and what will become the total number of cycles per incrementation.

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: you mean, like this?   for(int i = 0; i < 2^80; i++)

Comment: I'm using less-than, not less-than-or-equals, so I think the code is correct.  Are you using an embedded system, or running a windows app?

Comment: You're totally right. My bad.. That would be a windows app.

Comment: I think you'd have to look at the assembly code, then count up the number of clock cycles you'd need for each instruction (different for each instruction), then get the clock time, then do some simple math.  Of course, running this in a windows app would cause additional problems, because there's differences due to caching, & OS interrupts adding in extra differences.  IDK if that would be a reliable estimate... but this is how I did it a few times using an embedded system with M68000 assembly code.

Comment: Yep that should indeed give a correct estimation. I am still a bit worried about the fact that it's 80 bits though. I don't know how to take account of that. Anyways, I'll already have a look at the clock cycles of assembly instructions. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Joe: you can't just add up the cycles for all the instructions on out-of-order CPUs that can run independent instructions in parallel.  Caching isn't a big issue here, unless you're storing these 80bit values into an array.  If you're just updating the same memory location repeatedly, it will just stay hot in L1 cache so you can do one write per clock.  I posted an answer for recent x86 CPUs, mostly talking about Intel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summary: one clock cycle per value, storing the result to memory, is pretty easy on an out-of-order execution CPU.  Anything more than storing the results will be more overhead than incrementing.

Instruction throughput/latency and CPU execution pipeline info from [Agner Fog](http://agner.org/optimize/).

---

80 bits is larger than a single register on a normal 64bit CPU, so we'll need a pair of registers to hold the values.  i.e.

```
uint64_t high, low;  // or a struct, or a 2-element array
```

Regardless of being separate variables, or struct fields, or array elements, any decent compiler will keep them in registers.  `high` could be a 32bit variable.

There are two ways to go about incrementing this pair from 0 to 2^80-1:

- slow way: low+=1, high = add-with-cary(high, 0).
- fast way: double-nested loop:

```
low = 0;
for (high = 0 ; high < 1UL << (80-64) ; high++) {
    do {
        use_value(high,low);  // this point sees all 2^64 values of low
        low++;
    } while (low != 0);
    // low has wrapped to zero, so we don't even have to re-zero it
}
```

If you have to do this with 32bit code, use a triple-nested loop.  (using uint64_t in 32bit code probably does it the slow way, with an add-carry every time.)

This should compile to an inner-loop that takes only one cycle per iteration.  (Intel Haswell can do one-per-cycle loop iterations, but Intel Sandybridge only has a take-branch throughput of one per 2 cycles.)

I put this [on godbolt](https://goo.gl/nUPcUj), with store(memory_order_relaxed) to atomic globals as my `use(high,low)`, to prevent the loop from optimizing away.  A store has less overhead than a function call, and doesn't require mov instructions to get the variables into the correct registers.  It does in fact compile to a fairly good loop that should run one-per-clock on most CPUs.

When I had low++ before the atomic store, it used an extra `test` instruction, which is dumb.  It should just do:

```
loop80:
    xor edx, edx    # high
    xor eax, eax    # low
.Louter_loop:
    mov QWORD PTR global_h[rip], rdx    # or this could just be a 32bit store
.Linner_loop:
    mov QWORD PTR global_l[rip], rax    #,, low
    inc rax     # shorter encoding than add rax, 1
    jne .Linner_loop      # flags set by inc
 # inner loop is 2 fused-domain uops.  Or on AMD, 3 macro-ops since it can't fuse ALU ops with jcc

    inc edx     # only need to use the 32bit reg.
    cmp edx, 65536   # or count down from 65535 to zero, saving the cmp insn
    jne .Louter_loop

    ret
```

With loop-unrolling (`gcc -O3 -funroll-loops`), gcc and clang can use `lea` instructions to do low+1, low+2, low+3 etc. in parallel, so the loop-carried dependency is only low+=8.  This greatly lowers the branch throughput needed, but now the bottleneck becomes store throughput (one per clock).

If we left out the store, we could generate maybe 3 `low` values per clock in registers.  (Intel SnB and Haswell can run LEA on two execution ports, and fused arithmetic+branch on a 3rd port.)  This leaves no execution resources free to do *anything* with the values, but all you asked was enumerating them.  LEA is useful as a non-destructive 3-operand add operation.  Beating that throughput would require more LEA throughput, or a different CPU architecture.  e.g. most RISC CPUs (ARM, PowerPC, etc.) have 3-operand instructions for most ALU ops, instead of having dest = one of the src operands.  I haven't looked at instruction throughputs on the POWER architecture (and I find the instruction mnemonics really hard to read...), but it might be able to do 4 adds in parallel.  If so, it could beat Intel's x86 implementations on this microbenchmark.

Notice how we're *not* incrementing the global variable.  Having a store->load dependency in the dep chain would make it at least 6 cycles long.  Atomic increment (with `lock inc [mem]`) takes quite a bit longer.

---

So if you need to *do* anything with each bit pattern, even just store it in memory, that will dominate the running time.  If you *don't* need to store it, an out-of-order execution CPU running good code can generate multiple values in parallel per clock.  (Intel and AMD's current implementations can only store once per clock.)

---

If you want to start getting silly, it would be possible to use vector instructions to increment 16 (or 32, or 64 with AVX512) 8bit values and do a 16B (or 32B or 64B) store of that vector once per clock.  That wouldn't produce a contiguous 80bit value in memory, though, which is why I call it silly.